# Grails checkbox

Tags: grails

I have trouble with binding Boolean property in association classes. Property is set to **true** if I check checkbox (good), but is **null** if checbox is not checked.

I know the problem with HTML checkbox. I know why is send "_fieldName" in params, but this "_fieldName" dont set my boolean property to **false**.

```
class Person{
   String title

   List<Group> groups = new ArrayList()
   static hasMany = [groups: Groups]    
}

class Group{
   String title
   Boolean isHidden

   static belongTo = Person
}

class PersonController{

   def form = {
      def person = new Person()
      person.groups.add( new Group() )    
      return ["person": person]
   }

   def handleForm = {
      def person = new Person( params )
      println person.groups[0]
   }
}


 <g:form action="save">
    <g:textField name="title" value="${person?.title}" />
    <g:textField name="groups[0].title" value="${person?.groups[0]?.title}"/> 
    <g:checkBox name="groups[0].isHidden" value="${person?.groups[0]?.isHidden}"  />   
    <g:submitButton name="save" value="Save" />
  </g:form>
```

If I check checkbox:
[isHidden:on, title:a, _isHidden:]
println person.groups[0] //true

If I don check checkbox:
[title:a, _isHidden:]
println person.groups[0] //**null**

Thank a lot for help
Tom

I am sorry, I searched this web, but did not get actual info for my trouble.

Comment: Some GSP code could be useful here.

Comment: Hi Scott, I append GSP code. Thanks
Tom

Comment: This bug has not been patched on the grails github repo: https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy this was driving me crazy!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I correct checkbox tag. Thanks to gid help, now it work with association too.

from source:
http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/checkBox.html#

```
 if (value == null) value = false

out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_${name}\" /><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"${name}\" "

if (value && checked) { out << 'checked="checked" ' }
```

to:

```
if (value == null) value = false

def begin =  name.lastIndexOf('.') +1
def tail =  name.substring( begin);
out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name.replace(  tail, "_" + tail  )}\" /><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"${name}\" "

if (value && checked) { out << 'checked="checked" ' }
```

Comment: good stuff.. I'll see if I can create a test and patch for the grails project

Comment: Thanks this helps alot, i can't believe they have not fixed this yet.  I had to tweak the source a little bit.  But the general idea works.  You need to update the name of the hidden field.

Comment: I would suggest to use a template for rendering the input tag here. That would increase your readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 5):

After much hacking it appears the answer is that grails is looking for a marker field with the name:

```
groups[0]._isHidden
```

rather than

```
_groups[0].isHidden
```

which is actually what the `g:checkBox` tag generates. See [GrailsDataBinder.java:911](http://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/src/java/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/binding/GrailsDataBinder.java) see  propertyStartsWithFieldMarkerPrefix(PropertyValue pv, String fieldMarkerPrefix) for confirmation

If you are interested I've uploaded the test project for this question to [gitub.com](http://github.com/gid79/Q2937775-grails-checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below,

```
<g:checkBox name="checkbox" value="HELLO" />
```

Refer :

1. http://grails.asia/grails-checkbox-tag-example/
2. http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/checkBox.html

Answer (score 0):

Set the default value of the check-box to "false", and it should solve the issue.
Hope it helps.