# how to manage a one to many relationship - grails

Tags: grails

I have a simple problem.  I need to manage a hasMany collection on a domain object.  I thought I was doing it correct, but it didn't work.  I found another post but it is very dated and does not work ([Handling parameters from dynamic form for one-to-many relationships in grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505023/handling-parameters-from-dynamic-form-for-one-to-many-relationships-in-grails))

```
class User{
   static hasMany = ['prefs': Preference] 
}
class Preference{
  Boolean email
  Boolean site
  Date dateCreated
  Date lastUpdated

}
```

GSP

```
<g:each var="t" in="${user.prefs}" status="idx">            
  <li>
    <input type='hidden' name="prefs[${idx}].id" value="${t.id}"/>
    Email: <g:checkBox name="prefs[${idx}].email" value="${t.email}" />
    Site: <g:checkBox name="prefs[${idx}].site" value="${t.site}" /><
  </li>
</g:each>
```

Controller:

```
log.info(user.prefs)
user.properties = params
if(!user.save()){ ... }
```

It then errors out:

> UserController  - [Preference : 3, Preference : 4] 
>  
>    Error 2013-06-04 21:54:41,405 [http-bio-8080-exec-12] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver 
>  
>   IndexOutOfBoundsException occurred when processing request: [POST] /user/prefs - parameters:
>   prefs[0].email:
>   id: 2
>   prefs[1].site: on
>   prefs[0].email: on
>   _prefs[1].site:
>   _prefs[1].email:
>   prefs[1].id: 3
>   _prefs[0].site:
>   prefs[0].site: on
>   prefs[0].id: 4
>   Index: 1, Size: 1. Stacktrace follows:
>   Message: Index: 1, Size: 1

---

Comment: Does it error out saving the user after setting the properties? logs for `user.prefs` never showed `id` 1 and 2. Can you show the controller code and the POST url? BTW, if you are concerned about a particular order of which is has to be shown in gsp, then add `List prefs` in `User` domain. Adding `prefs` as items to a list in `User` maintains the index.

Comment: The logs for user.prefs shows `UserController - [Preference : 3, Preference : 4] ` which happens to be the two that are assigned.  Its not showing the idx, its showing the surroget key.

Comment: Can we have a look at the controller action as well?

Comment: What part of the controller? I posted the two lines

Comment: The action method and the POST URL. Your setup works great for me without any issue when I test it. To replicate the problem I am trying to clone your setup line by line.

Comment: I just updated my domain/gsp to be in the exact order i have it in mine.  hopefully that was messing you up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up fixing this and it was a hybrid approach.  @Meam was correct, it was an ordering issue, but instead of worrying about ordering I just used @dmahapatro 's approach and set Preference to be a list.  A side note on this is the definition of `List preference` has to come before the `static hasMany` definition.  Or you will get a random error when trying to create User.  Lastly, when you originally setup the relationship you have to use `addTo` to link the two...

```
class User{
  List preference
  static hasMany = ['prefs': Preference] 
}

//another thing I did not know in order to originaly link 
//the two when using lists, you have to use addTo...
user.addToPrefs(
    new Preference(email: true, site:false)
)
```

The last thing I wanted to mention is there is a bug in `<g:checkbox>` if you use it with a hasMany like I did it will not work if you try to uncheck the value.  I was able to work around it via coping the code from github for [FormTagLib](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-plugin-gsp/src/main/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/web/taglib/FormTagLib.groovy).  And then updated the code with the other post i was reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/2942667/256793 that has a solution but it was a little dated.  So here is the updated version:

```
 //old code
 //out  << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_${name}\""
 //new...
 def begin =  name.lastIndexOf('.') +1
 def tail =  name.substring( begin);
 out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${name.replace(  tail, "_" + tail  )}\" "
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this problem few days ago. And spent 2 days to fix it.

You have to make sure that children index in params is ordered same as parent's object. In this case, the children's order is [Preference: 3, Preference: 4]. But the params order is prefs[0].id = 4, prefs[1].id = 3. The order is different.

I have to reorder the children index in params before bind them.

Comment: You are right, there has to be a better way to do this.  Mine succeeds when they are in the right order, but fails if they are not.  It looks like its randomly sorting my by updateDate.